# Grunt.js watch - node_modules always being watched

Tags: gruntjs, livereload, node-modules

I'm using Grunt for livereload only. It works fine, but I noticed that it has high CPU, and when I run it with "--verbose" I see that it's watching the whole "node_modules" folder.

So, I made some research, and tried to ignore this. Unfortunately, with no success.

My watch part of "gruntfile.js" is:

```
    // the watch stuff ..
    watch: {
        all: {
            files: ['!**/node_modules/**', 'js/**/*.js', 'css/**/*.css', 'index.html'],
            options: {
                interval: 5007,
                livereload: true
            }
        }
    },
```

and basically I'm saying I want grunt to watch all js, css and the index.html file. Explicitly added the code for ignoring "node_modules", but it still says it's watching it and the CPU goes around 30%. (Mac OSx)

==================

One thing I noticed though:

When I make a change in the "gruntfile.js" - for example add one more file to the "files" property of the "watch" task - then it restarts the grunt, and in the console I see it start watching only the files I want, and then CPU goes below 1%. (I guess it's how it should be originally.)

What am I doing wrong?

====================

Edit: Unfortunately, when I change the gruntfile and I see only the files I want are being watched - then the livereload stuff is no longer working.

====================

This is the article I started from:
http://thecrumb.com/2014/03/15/using-grunt-for-live-reload/

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "grunt-reload",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "devDependencies": {
        "grunt": "~0.4.3",
        "matchdep": "~0.3.0",
        "grunt-express": "~1.2.1",
        "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.6.0",
        "grunt-open": "~0.2.3"
  }
}
```

And here is my Gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    require('matchdep')
        .filterDev('grunt-*')
        .forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);

    grunt.initConfig({

        // the web server ..
        express: {
            all: {
                options: {
                    bases: [__dirname],
                    port: 8888,
                    hostname: 'localhost',
                    livereload: true
                }
            }
        },

        // the watch stuff ..
        watch: {
            all: {
                files: ['js/**/*.js', 'css/**/*.css', 'index.html'],
                options: {
                    livereload: true
                }
            }
        },

        // the automatic opening stuff ..
        open: {
            all: {
                path: 'http://localhost:8888/index.html'
            }
        }
    });

    // create the server task ..
    grunt.registerTask(
        'server',
        ['express', 'open', 'watch']
    );

}; // end of "module.exports" ..
```

And I start all of this with "grunt server".

Answer (score 1):

edit: After you shared your Gruntfile, the problem became more clearer.

In your `grunt-express` config, you have set `livereload` to `true` and `bases` to `__dirname`, which is the folder `Gruntfile` in ran from.

Now, let's look at the `grunt-express` documentation:

> **bases**
>
> Type: String|Array Default: null
>
> The bases (or root) directories from which static files will be served. A connect.static() will be generated for each entry of bases. **When livereload is set to true (or set to a specific port number), a watch task will be created for you (at runtime) to watch your basePath/**/*.***.

(Emphasis mine)

So in your `grunt-express` config, you set your `livereload` to watch all the files in your basepath, which of course includes `node_modules`.

You have couple of options:

1. Remove your other `watch` task and config `grunt-expresses` basepath accordingly (just copy your other config basically).
2. Keep both of the watch tasks and just ignore the `node_modules` in the other `grunt-express -> bases` config.
3. Remove the `bases` and handle livereloading in the other `watch` task

---

Where is the `node_modules` folder located? If it's on root, you can just remove the `node_modules` parameter altogether as long as there aren't any matching glob patterns:

```
// the watch stuff ..
watch: {
    all: {
        files: ['js/**/*.js', 'css/**/*.css', 'index.html'],
        options: {
            interval: 5007,
            livereload: true
        }
    }
},
```

Now you are watching: All `.js`-files under `js` folder, `index.html` on root and so on.

However if you have `node_modules` under `js/node_modules`, you can the explicitly ignore that folder and the files in it:

```
 files: ['!js/node_modules/**', 'js/**/*.js', 'css/**/*.css', 'index.html'],
```

Anyway, depending on your Gruntfiles and `node_module`-folders location your configuration should work just fine anyway.

Comment: 'node_modules' is in the root. Currently I'm specifying only the files in "js" and "css" folders, as well as the index.html file - to be watched, but it still watches all and the CPU goes high.

Could it be the "all" word, and that's why it's watching absolutely everything in the root ? ...

Comment: That *shouldn't* have anything to do with the target name and looking at the source I can't find anything else pointing to that direction either... you don't happen to have other `watch`-targets than `all` in the config? Weird.

Comment: I added the content of both "package.json" and "Gruntfile.js" files, hopefully give some more info about this.

Comment: Thanks, that helped to understand the problem :) ... (I just removed "livereload:true" from the express configuration) and now it's fine - small CPU and watching + livereload functionality up and running :) .

Comment: (Btw, the comments on the original article are disabled :( ... and I can't add comment so other people don't run into the same problem.)

Comment: about the three options you've mentioned: ... how do you achieve (1) ... it's not clear for me and I can't understand it. About (2) - I added '!**/node_modules/**' to the "bases" array, but it had no effect ... is this what you meant? ... and for (3) - I removed the "bases" from the express config - and it gave me "Can not get ./index.html" ... but I'm not sure this is what you meant ... ... ... (I'm just still a newbie with grunt and it's still complex for me.)

Comment: Hmm, I thought that array would be a node globbing pattern but I might be wrong about that... which would lead to 1 and 2 not working (I haven't used grunt-express's `bases` myself). The number 3 is dependent on your server config, (particularly if you are using app.use(express.static(__dirname))), which setting the bases basically does.